# What does Lupin mean by the word "truth" here?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Lupin says to Harry:

> Lupin: The last time Voldemort gained power...he almost destroyed
> everything we hold most dear. Now he's returned, and I'm afraid the
> minister will do almost anything...to avoid facing that terrifying
> **truth**.

What does he mean by the word "truth" in this context?

Comment: The truth that Voldie has returned.

Comment: I know this is really more of an English Language question than actually about SF&F, but it is really worthy of down voting? It seems a bit harsh when the answer is getting a substantial number of upticks.

Comment: @jontia, from my perspective it doesn't show much if any research effort, or explanation why the word is hard to understand in this context. Regardless though downvotes, by definition can be given for almost any reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "terrifying truth" is the fact that Voldemort returned, which Fudge is shown to deny in the part immediately before:

> [Kingsley shows Harry a newspaper with the headline "The Boy who Lies?"]
>
> Sirius:
> He's been attacking Dumbledore as well. Fudge is using all his power, including his influence at the Daily Prophet, to smear anyone who claims the Dark Lord has returned.

Quote via [quotes.net](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/115633)

Answer (score 0):

From an English language perspective,  "[truth](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/truth)" here is used as a synonym of fact or [actuality](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/actuality).

> **Actuality**
> noun: something that truly exists, is real